# How to paint on canvas? 

Tags: html, canvas

Can you tell me how to paint on a canvas?  Here is the html 5 code :

```
 var TableHeight = 300,
     TableWidth = 500,    
 function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    table.draw();
}

table = {
    color: '#000',
    PositionX : 1,
    PositionY: 1,
    width: TableWidth,
    height: TableHeight,
    draw: function(){
        context.fillStyle = this.color;
        context.fillRect = (this.PositionX, this.PositionY, this.width, this.height);
        context.clearRect(5, 5, TableWidth - 10, TableHeight - 10);
    }
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<body>
    <canvas id ='canvas' width = 500px height = 300px ></canvas>
    <script>init()</script>
</body>
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I assume there is something wrong in the code , please point out your exact query in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

Firstly: Your function declaration, as far as I can see, is wrong.  It does not get defined as after your last global variable, you put a comma, instead of a semi-colon.  The below is how to correctly define your function, since you aren't doing it through a variable:

```
var TableHeight = 300,
    TableWidth = 500;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    table.draw();
}
```

Lastly, while `.fillStyle` is a property, and not a method, the same is not true of `.fillRect()`, which is indeed a method and needs to be executed as such:

```
var table = {
    color: '#000',
    PositionX: 1,
    PositionY: 1,
    width: TableWidth,
    height: TableHeight,
    draw: function() {
        context.fillStyle = this.color;
        context.fillRect(this.PositionX, this.PositionY, this.width, this.height);
        context.clearRect(5, 5, TableWidth - 10, TableHeight - 10);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7ref/3/)

Comment: @user1724080 If this solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the oulined checkmark under the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `fillRect`, `fillStyle` etc are methods, not properties. You need to call them like so:

```
context.fillStyle(this.color);
```

Refer the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial) for more info and samples

You should also look at [Douglas Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) website for pointers on good Javascript style. For instance, you are omitting the `var` keyword in certain places, which causes the variable to become a global, unintentionally.